# Serializer return incorrect output

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model:

```py
class Route(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Номер маршрута", max_length=100)
    evotor_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name="пользователь эвотор", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nds_CHOICES = (
        (0, 'БЕЗ НДС'),
        (1, 'Основная ставка 0%'),
        (2, 'Основная ставка 10%'),
        (3, 'Расчётная ставка 10%'),
        (4, 'Основная ставка 18%'),
        (5, 'Расчётная ставка 18%')
    )
    nds = models.IntegerField('НДС', choices=nds_CHOICES, default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Номер маршрута"
        verbose_name_plural = "Номера маршрутов"
```

And I have serializer for that model:

```py
class RouteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Route
        fields = ("id", "name", "nds")
```

My APIView

```py
class CarView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (BearerAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    def get(self, request):
        if 'route_id' not in request.GET or request.GET['route_id']=="":
            #return Response({'message': 'Не указан ID маршрута'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            car = Car.objects.filter(evotor_user=request.user)
        else:
            car = Car.objects.filter(route__id=request.GET['route_id'])
        serializer = CarSerializer(car, many=True)
        print(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

use this serializer

```py
class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    route = RouteSerializer
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ("id", "name", "route")
```

and  must return me output like this:
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "dfgdfgdfg",
        "route": {
            'id': 1,
            'name': 'route_name',
            'nds': 0,
        }
    }
]

But it returns:
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "dfgdfgdfg",
        "route": 1
    }
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CarSerializer.route` declaration is wrong. It must be an **instance** of `RouteSerializer`, like this:

```
class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    route = RouteSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ("id", "name", "route")
```

This is called "nested relationship", see docs at https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships